# Character creator and clothing, how to make the assets?

Tags: blender, assets, character, character-development, unreal-5

By going inside some game files of big games, it seems a lot of armors, when equiped on the characters will straight out delete their body beneat.

for example, if you wear an helmet, underneat it, all the unseen head polygons are just deleted.

This is very smart to make the game more performing and lighter, but seems really tedious to take every single character and crop out their bodies to fit every single armature, then making sure that the animations still work even with the armor and clothing on.

So I'm pretty sure studios have a better method, maybe something that does it automatically.

Since I wanna make a character creator+armors+wigs+clothes in my game, how does this method work and how can I apply it if I use unreal engine 5 as a game engine and blender to make my assets?

Do I really have to crop every single model and re-animate it?

Comment: [I was just digging up this Q&A from last year for another user](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/188675/39518). While it's described in the context of Unity, the approach applies to other engines too. You don't need to make new body models and re-animate them for each body chunk removed (or combination of chunks). Instead, you can have a single animated model and then cull out pieces of it  - either by disabling sub-meshes, aborting triangles based on vertex attributes, or even doing per-pixel masking.

Comment: Have you looked at shape keys? That might be the simplest way to hide parts of the mesh, although it doesn't delete the mesh. Sebastion Lague discusses the technique in this series: https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0f4c56CbvYi038zmCmoZ4CQ

Comment: @GaleRazorwind oh my god I've been looking for this playlist since december, for real couldn't find anything on google nor youtube