# Teeth sticking out from character clothing mask shader

Tags: shaders

So this issue happens after using a character clothing shader here

[How do you have the clothing mesh hide the body mesh underneath?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/188675/how-do-you-have-the-clothing-mesh-hide-the-body-mesh-underneath)

[image: Image from Gyazo]

i'm not sure what is causing this exactly? how do we fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're using transparent blending. Have you tried using alpha testing instead so you get correct opaque sorting?

Comment: you can avoid the problem althogether by slicing he character into pieces instead of using shaders .